# Disable the enter key in react-select while loading data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I stop the Enter action if prop isLoading is "true"?

Use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

```
const handleChange = (value) => { 
  //Stop this code while props.isLoading is true  
} 

return ( <Select onInputChange={handleChange} isLoading={props.isLoading} /> )
```

Thanks

Comment: help us help you and add relevant code please

Comment: ```....
const handleChange = (value) => {
  Stop this code while props.isLoading is true
}

return (
  <Select onInputChange={handleChange} isLoading={props.isLoading} />
)

...```

Condition if(props.isLoading) not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple `if` considtion :

```
const handleChange = (value) => { 
  //Stop this code while props.isLoading is true 
  if(!this.state.isLoading) {
    // this part will not execute if this.state.isLoading is true
    // put the code here for when this.state.isLoading is false
  }
} 


return ( <Select onInputChange={handleChange} isLoading={props.isLoading} /> )
```